# Use Python setup.py to install different dependencies with develop vs install

Tags: python, setuptools, pelican

In some of my python packages, I specify additional packages required for development. I do this using the `extras_requires` functionality located in the `setup.py` file. Technically, these files are not required for an `install`, but they are required specifically for during development.

My problem is, that when I use the `setup.py` file and specify the "develop" flag, `$ python setup.py develop`, there's no way that I currently know to add additional packages to be installed by with pip in the "develop" versus a normal `install` mode.

So my question is, is there a way to denote additional packages that need to be installed when the command `$ python setup develop` is run, instead of the normal `$ python setup install`.

I'm specifically looking at the use case of a python Pelican blog, where I use a module called `ghp-import` to push to Github pages, which can be seen [here](https://github.com/benhoff/blog/blob/master/setup.py#L22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I know of is to use *pip*, for example:

```
$ pip install --editable .[dev]
```